# Close Serial port connection handler from different process

Tags: c#, .net, process, serial-port, .net-4.5

I encountered a strange scenario for our product software upgrade, the requirement is we need to close the serial port opened by main process from a different process.

Doing above will simplify our software upgrade process. The solution avoids many workarounds in different areas like customer s/w installation process, product manufacturing installation, software builds.. etc

In a naive terms:
Main process opened a serial port communication with scanner and alive, we have a different process say Process2 which assist the software upgrade procedure. During software upgrade procedure "Process2" need to open a serial port connection with scanner, since the port is already occupied by Main process we get  following error from Process2 "Access to the path 'COM1' is denied."

Tried following solutions:
1) Inherit the SerialPort class hide the implementation of Open() , try disposing the same port immediately. Copied the idea from following stackoverflow thread

[stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414043/can-i-get-the-device-handle-for-a-serial-port-that-i-am-accessing-using-the-net)

2)Tried reflection on SerialPort object on a new instance before opening the connection, and try to get the Handle of serial port and dispose, did not work.I get null reference exception in line2

```
var serialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM1");
object stream = typeof(SerialPort).GetField("internalSerialStream", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(serialPort);
var handle = (SafeFileHandle)stream.GetType().GetField("_handle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(stream);
```

I was hesitant from starting , is this possible? If so , help on getting technical solution

Comment: Why not kill process 1 from process 2, do the upgrade, then restart process 1?

Comment: Our s/w upgrade procedure depends on Process1, to complete s/w upgrade successfully, we need to end the Process1 gracefully. So killing Process1 is not a solution.